# Need help learning how to create the depth in the polygon in this image using photoshop

Tags: photoshop-effects

[image]is there a photoshop tutorial or an easy way to make the hexagon with the corners the way they are in this picture? I'm not really sure where to start. I've googled different things, but since I don't know the name of the effect being used it's not easy finding a tutorial on my own. [![][2]][2]

Comment: This looks like a combination of drop shadows and masks, with each hexagon being on its own layer, and text on the very bottom.

Comment: So it's not the shadows falling on the ground and the hexagons you are interested in, but the gradient shading of the hexagons themselves?

Comment: i updated the image in the original post, but i'd like to recreate the effect where the angles meet.

Comment: What about the ieffect at the intersections are you interested in - the difference in shading? I don't think photoshop offers an automatic way of doing that - you may need to do this manually.

Comment: Its just 6 different gradients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Illustrator, because vector shapes are there handled much more easily and there's no need to worry the resolution.

But everything is possible also in Photoshop, the handling is only more complex. You must make careful selections or use vector masks.

I drew a polygon, made a smaller copy, made a hole by subtracting and splitted the resulted ring  to pieces with lines and Object > Path > Divide objects below.

The pieces were kept together, they got only different gradient fills.

In the next image there's shown some intermediate results and a copy of the splitted polygon ring ripped apart to show the separate pieces. One actual fill gradient is also shown:

[image]

I made a smaller copy of a ring, inserted a background, a Lorem ipsum text variant and some blurred grey polygon ring copies  with very low opacity. I got this piece:

[image]

Comment: Juuri näin se menee. Mitähän suomalaista traktori osaketta kannatais ostaa.

Comment: @user287001 - thank you for the samples, i'm going to try this!

Comment: @joojaa that decision shouldn't be based on subjective recommendations. Check some objective third party scientific reports like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtV0PKWrciE

Comment: Update: I was able to do it pretty simply in photoshop - I used the polygon shape tool to draw a hexagon (with just a stroke, no fill) then I used the polygon lasso tool to select each side and then added the gradient. Now I'm just playing with the gradient to get it how I want it to look.

I also will need to add the drop shadow.

@user287001 - how did you get the polygons to intersect like that?

Comment: @stephie.steph the polygons are splitted to pieces, which are stacked to wrong order. In Photoshop you can make the same by having more image layers.